# Rails: How do I get only the saved models with .collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Post that `has_many` of model Comment.

On a `Posts` `show` action, there is a list of `Comments` found with `@comments = @post.comments`.

I also have a form for creating new `Comments`. The form has its object created with `@comment = @post.comments.build`.

This all works for listing and successfully creating comments.

The problem occurs when there is an error when the comment is submitted. The errors are shown in the same form (so, on `Post#show`) via `render "posts/show"`.
In this case, I have to set `@comments = @post.comments` again, but this time the list of comments includes the not-yet-saved comment that the user is trying to create.

I solved it by using `@post.comments.all`, which only gives me the saved models, but Rails complains that this is deprecated in Rails 4.

How do I remove the unsaved comment from the list of comments I get from `@post.comments`?

Comment: You can also use the .new_record? method on collection items to filter out the new ones.

Comment: 1. In Rails 4 you should use `to_a` to evaluate the query. 2. Use 'new_record?' to find new records. You can also clear the errors if you don't want to show them for newly created comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a scope to the comment model to find only database rows instead of in memory data, for example:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_post, ->(post) { where(post: post) }
end
```

called by: `@comments = Comment.by_post(@post)`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue with a Rails 5 application. This seemed like the most straightforward approach:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build
@comments = @post.comments.where.not(id: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way imho is just to ignore the new record in the view, instead of retrieving all comments again.

So in your view you will do something like:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :comments do |c|
  - unless c.object.new_record? 
    = render 'comment_fields', :f => c
```

Comment: I show the incomplete comment in the form with errors and all. I just want to remove the incomplete comment from the list of "real" comments.

Comment: @nathanvda The question is asking how to remove the unsaved/invalid record from the list, not the form.

Comment: While my answer might not answer the question directly, imho it is the best approach in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can force load the comments. You have to do it like this:-

```
@comments = @post.comments(true)
```